# Compara dos carpetas distintas para que tengan los mismos archivos las carpetas

Tags: python, windows

Esoy comenzando con Python y quiero resolver el problema que tengo con el siguiente código que no funciona correctamente. A veces me funciona y otras veces me da error "*OSError: [WinError 123] El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos*".

El código esta realizado para que ambas carpetas, que en inicio tienen  distinto número de archivos, y los archivos siguen una nomenclatura identica, que tras el código los archivos que no existan en alguna de las carpetas sean eliminados para que finalmente ambas carpetas tengan los mismos archivos puesto que su nombre es identico.

¿Dónde esta el error de que no me funcione el código?

```
import glob
from pathlib import Path   
import os

#Defino la carpeta y elementos a listar DE MAYOR ARCHIVOS
carpeta_A_lista = []
for img in glob.glob('/Users/Usuario/Desktop/COMPARACION_2000_OK/1.000/1.000_PERFECTO/16/1_S/*.jpg'):
    fname= Path(img).name
    carpeta_A_lista.append(fname)


#Defino la carpeta y elementos a listar carpeta REFERENCIA
carpeta_B_lista = []
for img in glob.glob("/Users/Usuario/Desktop/COMPARACION_2000_OK/1.000/1.000_PERFECTO/19/1_S/*.jpg"):
    fname2= Path(img).name
    carpeta_B_lista.append(fname2)
    

print (('El número de archivos que tiene la carpeta DE MAYOR ARCHIVOS es de:  ') , (len(carpeta_A_lista)))

print (('El número de archivos que tiene la carpeta REFERENCIA es de:  ') , (len(carpeta_B_lista))) 

files_un_matched =  [x for x in carpeta_A_lista if x not in carpeta_B_lista]

for x in files_un_matched:
    fullpath_duplicate_image =os.path.join('/Users/Usuario/Desktop/COMPARACION_2000_OK/1.000/1.000_PERFECTO/16/1_S/*.jpg', x) #Defino la carpeta y elementos a listar DE MAYOR ARCHIVOS
    os.remove(fullpath_duplicate_image)

carpeta_A_lista = []
for img in glob.glob("/Users/Usuario/Desktop/COMPARACION_2000_OK/1.000/1.000_PERFECTO/16/1_S/*.jpg"):
    fname= Path(img).name
    carpeta_A_lista.append(fname)

carpeta_B_lista = []
for img in glob.glob("/Users/Usuario/Desktop/COMPARACION_2000_OK/1.000/1.000_PERFECTO/19/1_S/*.jpg"):
    fname2= Path(img).name
    carpeta_B_lista.append(fname2)

print (('El número de archivos que tiene la carpeta QUE ORININALMENTE TENIA MÁS ARCHIVOS es de:  ') , (len(carpeta_A_lista)))


print (('El número de archivos que tiene la carpeta REFERENCIA es de:  ') , (len(carpeta_B_lista)))
```

Comment: Es posible que sea porque te falta indicar la unidad en la ruta (`C:`, `D:` o lo que fuese).

Answer (score 0):

El comodín * se utiliza para hacer referencia a todos los archivos que cumplan con un determinado patrón en un directorio, pero en este caso, se está utilizando en la ruta del archivo, lo que causa el error que mencionas.

Si quieres utilizar el comodín para seleccionar todos los archivos .jpg de una carpeta, deberías utilizarlo en la función glob en lugar de en la ruta del archivo. Por ejemplo:

```
for img in glob.glob('/Users/Usuario/Desktop/COMPARACION_2000_OK/1.000/1.000_PERFECTO/16/1_S/*.jpg'):
    fname= Path(img).name
    carpeta_A_lista.append(fname)
```

De esta manera, se seleccionarán todos los archivos .jpg de la carpeta, pero la ruta del archivo se guardará sin el comodín *, lo que evitará el error que mencionas.